# TYPO 3 Localization : getting translation in several languages in one time

Tags: localization, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use TYPO3 6.2.

In my extension, I need to get a l10n label in several languages at one time.

I know how to do that for the current front end language using:

`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate($key, $extName, $args)`

How do I get the label in another language, other than the one used in front end?

Comment: https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_localization_utility.html#a2b440788bed6b7815080fd356521699b could be an option

Comment: Exactly what I need... If I will find an answer I'll keep you posted. Curently, my best bet is to make my own xlf parser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my project deadline is "yesterday", I've done it the following way. Maybe you can use it also, because I think asked feature is not supported by Typo3 LocalizationUtility...

Anyway, I added duplicated entries with a diferent key:

```
<trans-unit id="tx_auslastung_domain_model_therme.text.0">
    <source>We are looking forward to your visit!</source>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="tx_auslastung_domain_model_therme.text.0-en">
    <source>We are looking forward to your visit!</source>
</trans-unit>
```

and in German xlf I have

```
<trans-unit id="tx_thermenauslastung_domain_model_therme.text.0">
     <source>We are looking forward to your visit!</source> 
     <target>Wir freuen uns auf Ihren Besuch!</target>
</trans-unit>
```

So this way I can use Typo3 LocalizationUtility normaly, and if I need "en" text, then I read the same key with appended "-en".

Btw. my default Typo3 language is DE.

I know this is not a perfect solution.
You should never use this, if there is better way.

In my defance, it works, and duplicated entries are in the .xlf file, that is a mess anyway. xD